# Can I pass an exception as an argument to a function in python?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am new to python. I am trying to create a retry decorator that, when applied to a function, will keep retrying until some criteria is met (for simplicity, say retry 10 times).

```
def retry():
    def wrapper(func):
        for i in range(0,10):
            try:
                func()
                break
            except:
               continue
    return wrapper
```

Now that will retry on any exception. How can I change it such that it retries on specific exceptions. e.g, I want to use it like:

```
@retry(ValueError, AbcError)
def myfunc():
    //do something
```

I want `myfunc` to be retried only of it throws `ValueError` or `AbcError`.

Comment: Added a `break` now. Thanks!. Edit: I think it was wrong logic for retry. I just need the `for` loop I think

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can supply a `tuple` of exceptions to the `except ..` block to catch:

```
from functools import wraps

def retry(*exceptions, **params):
    if not exceptions:
        exceptions = (Exception,)
    tries = params.get('tries', 10)

    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            for i in range(tries):
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kw)
                except exceptions:
                    pass
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

The catch-all `*exceptions` parameter will always result in a tuple. I've added a `tries` keyword as well, so you can configure the number of retries too:

```
@retry(ValueError, TypeError, tries=20)
def foo():
    pass
```

Demo:

```
>>> @retry(NameError, tries=3)
... def foo():
...     print 'Futzing the foo!'
...     bar
... 
>>> foo()
Futzing the foo!
Futzing the foo!
Futzing the foo!
```

Comment: Actually you can catch a "variable exception or a tuple of things you can catch", but that tends to make my head hurt if I think about it too long.

Comment: @glglgl: it needed a little more than just `return wrapper` to make this a proper decorator factory.

Comment: I wonder if it would be useful to even parametrize the `10` with `def retry(*exceptions, **config):` and `for i in range(0, config.get('retries', 10)):`. It was not requested by the OP, but it is maybe quite useful...

Comment: Related question - What if I want to catch and rethrow the exception if it is still failing after 10 tries?

Comment: @Raze2dust: Call `raise` at the end of the wrapper. It'll raise the last caught exception; you don't *have* to do that in the `except` clause.

Answer (score 2):

```
from functools import wraps

class retry(object):
    def __init__(self, *exceptions):
        self.exceptions = exceptions

    def __call__(self, f):
        @wraps(f) # required to save the original context of the wrapped function
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            for i in range(0,10):
                try:
                    f(*args, **kwargs)
                except self.exceptions:
                    continue
        return wrapped
```

Usage:

```
@retry(ValueError, Exception)
def f():
    print('In f')
    raise ValueError


>>> f()
In f
In f
In f
In f
In f
In f
In f
In f
In f
In f
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the error class:

```
except Exception as e:
    for et in error_types: #(or args)
        if isinstance(e, et):
            continue
    raise e #re-raise
```

Comment: You can except an iterable object (e.g. tuple, list) with exceptions, so no need to iterate later.